# Is there a way to apply CSS styles to React components without directly importing CSS files into the component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The problem at hand is about finding alternative methods to apply CSS styles to React components without directly importing CSS files into the component.

I attempted to use inline styles by defining styles within JavaScript objects directly in the component JSX. While this approach worked well for simpler styling needs, it became cumbersome and less maintainable for larger stylesheets or complex styling requirements.

Comment: you could use tailwindCss. Its basically a framework where you dont need to import css and can use classes in tags itself like using inline styles

Comment: But it was also pushing me to implement the `@import` statements in my React app to use Tailwind CSS in React components, or another method to import Tailwind CSS using a `<link>` tag in the HTML header. However, it was not ideal to add many files to the HTML `<header>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

With most bundler setups you could typically do:

```
// App.tsx or equivalent top-level component

import "./style.css";
...
```

If this fails, you would have to include the relevant config for your bundler/framework.

Comment: Importing CSS files directly, like `import "./style.css";`, is a common way to include styles in a React application using bundlers like Webpack or frameworks like Create React App. While this method is typically effective, I'm interested in exploring alternative ways to apply styles without directly importing CSS files into components.

Comment: @Anu why not then do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can put internal as well external css for any of your project.

if you want the import the css file without importing in component,
you have to import in the main app component as

```
import "./style.css";
//or
@import url('');
```

or you can host your css file externally( such as https://github.com) and import in you project.

Comment: How the above implementation will works?

Comment: just upload the css file to public repo and use it as @import url('');